# Hololens bootstrapping failed on specific Hololens device

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

This error only occurs on one out of the three Hololenses we have available here, and it also only appears to be only on my PC.

```
   Error        DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. 
   SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no device was detected. Make 
   sure a device is connected and powered on.  [0x80131500] Dura Demo
```

This is a Unity project build using Unity 2017.3.06b with VS15.4.1, Windows SDK 10.16299.15.

Experimental .NET 4.6

Build type XAML

Using the latest Holotoolkit, HUX MRDesignlabs.

Comment: please send me the hololense, Ill try it here ;o)
if you can not do that, maybe try switching to other ports or reinstalling the drivers :/

Comment: That error shows when device is not connected. So either it is not connected or you have connecting hardware issue. Try resetting the device maybe. Does it charge when you plug it? Also, can you connect with computer? Try connecting and type http://127.0.0.1:10080 in browser to see if it connects.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that but I tried to connect via 192.162.20.48 and it doesn't seem to respond.

Comment: @Florian He asked you to connect to `127.0.0.1:10080` from your browser and see what happens but you  did something irrelevant and did not respond to that comment. Just paste  `127.0.0.1:10080` to your Firefox, IE or Chrome where you usually type your url and press enter. That's it.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't seem to do anything "This site can’t be reached".

Comment: Reply to @Everts as he's the one that asked for that info. `http://127.0.0.1:10080` should take you to the portal otherwise there is a problem. Is your Hololens connected to your Wifi? If not, make sure your computer and Hololens are connected to the-same Wifi.

Comment: Actually this is not through wifi, it is the USB port.

Comment: Yeah i figured, I tried it with the cable in.

Comment: @Everts I've seen people having problems connecting to `http://127.0.0.1:10080` with USB but Wifi solved their issue then it works with USB even when Wifi is now disconnected. It's worth trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my experience the HL2 also has this problem sometimes the only thing you can do is use another USB port, use another cable or try to sideload a package from the portal.